# BigQuery converting string to datetime

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, google-bigquery, udf

I'm using BigQuery to try I have a table with a string column called 'DATAUTILIZACAO' that has the following sample values:

> 02/11/16 12:19:08,000000
>
> 02/11/16 17:39:41,000000

The text is formatted as "DD/MM/YY HH:mm:ss"
I need to create a new column of type **DATETIME** containing the value of **DATAUTILIZACAO**.

How can I get the value from **DATAUTILIZACAO** format it as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS" and save it to the new column?

Can I do that using Query+UDF directly ?

Thanks,

Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below (for Standard SQL - see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql))

```
WITH TheTable AS (
  SELECT '02/11/16 12:19:08,000000' AS DATAUTILIZACAO UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/11/16 17:39:41,000000' AS DATAUTILIZACAO 
)
SELECT DATAUTILIZACAO, PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,000000', DATAUTILIZACAO) AS parsedDATAUTILIZACAO
FROM TheTable
```

see more on [PARSE_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_timestamp)

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants `DATETIME` values, though, not `TIMESTAMP`s.

Comment: i think, it is close enough for OP to do little extra step :o)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PARSE_DATETIME`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime-functions) to get a `DATETIME` value from the strings using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"). For example,

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT DATAUTILIZACAO
  FROM UNNEST(['02/11/16 12:19:08,000000',
               '02/11/16 17:39:41,000000']) AS DATAUTILIZACAO
)
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%D %T,000000', DATAUTILIZACAO) AS dt
FROM T;
```