# Bigquery convert string to datetime

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to parse a string to a datetime format. I am posting here after exploring this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40411938/bigquery-converting-string-to-datetime)

Here is my attempt at it, what am i missing?

`select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%M-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000', StartDate) AS parsedStartDate`

This is the error I get: Failed to parse input string "2020-11-23T10:51:47.5533333"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in standard SQL:

```
with data as (
select '2020-11-23T10:51:47.5533333' as StartDate
)
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S',StartDate) from data;
```